# MySQL connection reset in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a java code that generate and fill tables to MySQL database.

The method is to create a connection to generate a table and then close that connection afterward.
Then create new connection to fill the table and so on.

I have about 14000 table to generate. The problem is that after generating about 800 tables I got this message and I have to restart mysql again.

Is there a cap to the number of connection I could create? is there anyway to increase it? Any Ideas?

Thanks

```
java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.net.SocketException, underlying cause:  Connection reset

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Connection reset

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1449)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1803)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:2353)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:750)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1627)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:395)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at db.DbConnection.establishConnection(DbConnection.java:21)
    at db.DbActivities.addToDocSent(DbActivities.java:125)
    at db.DbGeneration.main(DbGeneration.java:58)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Comment: are you creating a new connection for each table?

Comment: Need to look at some code here.

Comment: Yes, otherwise I will got too many connection exception.

Comment: That comment above has no sense at all....

Comment: Hm... then why don't you use just one connection?

Comment: Thanks guys, one connection did the trick